# SQL Server 2008 Profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

How can I Filter only my calls to Shared SQL Server using a shared login account when debugging?

I am using SQL Profiler and was curious if anybody knows the Column Filters I can use to focus only to my calls.

I have the LoginName set to the Account that multiple users are using and that still does not filter enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SPID column.

Find out what SPID you are using (if profiling from SSMS, it is in the status bar) and filter by it.

Another option is to include an application name (possibly with the specific machine name) in the connection string and filter by it.

Comment: You said **PID** did you mean **SPID**???   Also I do not see that in the status bar of SSMS.

Comment: @Moojjoo - in the status bar, when you have a query window open, you will see the user name and SPID `username (spid)`. And sorry, yes, it is SPID, not PID.